# Prevent network card disabled on suspend

Tags: suspend, wakeonlan

Since upgrading to 14.04 I can no longer wake on lan my laptop. This is because the network card seems to be disabled when I suspend ubuntu.

Is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Prevent suspending or prevent network card to be disabled when suspending?

Comment: Prevent network card being disabled edited for clarification, ty